# find last occurrence using java and regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm receiving  HTML code from XML and trying to find last  in Java.
when I'm running the code I always receive the first span and the groupCount show me that there is only one match (the first one).
I also tried to use a hardcode version of the XML (I created a string variable and still got the same result)

here is my code:

```
String text = "<div><ul ><li><span>answer 1.</span></li><li><span>answer 2</span></li><li><span>answer3.</span></li><li><span>answer 4</span></li></ul><div><span>Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3</span></div></div>"
    Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("<span.*?(?=</span>)");
    Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(desc);
    if (matcher3.find()) {
        int result = matcher3.groupCount();
        String s = (matcher3.group(result))//->>always show the first result 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [find the last match with java/regex/matcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417435/find-the-last-match-with-java-regex-matcher)

Comment: You're using `groupCount()` incorrectly.  What it tells you is how many capturing groups there in the regex.  That's a static property of the Pattern object; it doesn't tell you anything about what was matched.  Your regex has no groups, so `groupCount()` always returns zero.

Comment: Do not parse HTML using regular expressions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Andreas He is not parsing HTML but just finding a particular string within a larger string, which IMHO is fine. Also, we know that post, [you can stop linking](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `matcher.find` again and it wll find the next match. It does not only tell you whether it found anything, it also actively searches for the next match. After you called it once, you only get the first match. When you call it again, next time you call `matcher.group` you get the second match, and so on. Repeat until it finds nothing, than take the last result. Also, you do not really need `groupCount`, as there is always the same number of groups in the match -- zero.

```
String text = "<div><ul ><li><span>answer 1.</span></li><li><span>answer 2</span></li><li><span>answer3.</span></li><li><span>answer 4</span></li></ul><div><span>Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3</span></div></div>";
Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("<span.*?(?=</span>)");
Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(text);
String s = null;
while (matcher3.find()) {
    s = matcher3.group();
} 
System.out.println(s);
```

Output is `<span>Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3`.

If you want to use just what's within the `<span>` tags, you can use regex `"<span>(.*?)</span>"` and `matcher3.group(1)` to get what's within the first pair of `()` (or put the tags in lookahead and lookbehind, but IMHO it's easier this way).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Though you have asked for finding last occurence using regex. But also consider using jsoup which is java tested library for html parser. Its already tested and good from readability point of view

See [finding last occurrence using jsoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#last--)

Answer (score 0):

Use a greedy quantifier `*` with `.` to find the last occurence.

```
(?s)^.*<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>
```

Captures of first group `matcher3.group(1)` [regexplanet demo](http://fiddle.re/w9t746)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
String text = "<div><ul ><li><span>answer 1.</span></li><li><span>answer 2</span></li><li><span>answer3.</span></li><li><span>answer 4</span></li></ul><div><span>Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3</span></div></div>"
    Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile("<span.*?(?=</span>)");
    Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(text);
    if (matcher3.find()) {
        String in= matcher3.group(matcher3.groupCount()); 
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as OPs code (including the wrong variable name), just that it does not declare the int var but use the result directly.

Comment: still it will print 1st occurence