# How to capture certain text within a StringBuffer Java

Tags: java, regex, xml, string, stringbuffer

I have a StringBuffer object with the following contents:

```
<ET>read input: 1.629ms</ET>
<ET>There were 3 errors:
<Error>
    <ErrorId>AllConditionsTrue</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Balance Due</Key>
            <Value>1500.99</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>

<Error>
    <ErrorId>Opposite</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Node</Key>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>

<Error>
    <ErrorId>minInclusive</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Description</Key>
            <Value>Wages Amount</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>

: 0.027ms</ET>
<ET>convert: 319.414ms</ET>
<FORM id="123"/>
<DATA size="11920"/>
<ERROR code="0"/>
```

How can I capture just the text which is at and within the Error Tags (`<Error>` some text `</Error>` ). So my new String or StringBuffer object contains:

```
<Error>
    <ErrorId>AllConditionsTrue</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Balance Due</Key>
            <Value>1500.99</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>

<Error>
    <ErrorId>Opposite</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Node</Key>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>

<Error>
    <ErrorId>minInclusive</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Description</Key>
            <Value>Wages Amount</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>
```

How can I accomplish my goal using Java?

**Edit**

Trying both your guys solutions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Error>.*?<\\/Error>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(buf.toString());

String errorText = "";

while (m.find()) {
    errorText = m.group(1);
}
```

I seem to only get 3 error tag element not all 3.

Example:

```
<Error>
    <ErrorId>minInclusive</ErrorId>
    <MetaData>
        <Entry>
            <Key>Description</Key>
            <Value>Wages Amount</Value>
        </Entry>
    </MetaData>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced with StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your string contains new lines, so you have to use `\n`. Try this out:

```
<Error>((?:.*?\n?)+.*?)<\/Error>
```

Check the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lS5kJ1/2)

Comment: Trying your solution now

Comment: Thanks, your solution works for this particular problem. Now will this work for any number of Error tags?

Comment: Updated. Try it out :)

Comment: It didn't seem to work, I now only get 1 error Tag :(

Comment: This is what I tried (escaping the closing error tag) `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<Error>((?:.*?\n?)+.*?)<\\/Error>", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: You have forgotten to double \\ at new line character \\n. You have only single one \n.

Comment: Whoops, I'm terrible at regex. Would something like this `"<Error>((?:.*?\\n?)+.*?)<\\/Error>"` do? Because this still gives only 1 error tag

Comment: @arabian_albert `while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}` It may print all 3. `errorText = m.group(1);` you will only get the last one, other is overwrite because  in loop, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417435/find-the-last-match-with-java-regex-matcher

Comment: @Tim007 got it! Thanks for the linked post

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
<Error>.*?<\/Error>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iN7jV5/1)

Comment: Thanks but this regex only seems to grab one Error tag element, see my edit to the original post

Comment: @arabian_albert  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex

Comment: Thanks @Tim007 I definitely need to readup on regex

Answer (score 1):

SaxParse would be a better solution than string parser.

It will be portable for your future references as well.

Refer this sax documentation :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html